# Best practices to create git repos of the same software with small changes

Tags: git

I am facing a problem which is being hard to find a solution:

I have one big git repo which contains a software I have built. I have installed this repo in some servers. The software is customised according to the project/server. The problem is, I think it is a waist of space  pushing to remote all the software just because I have changed some files. I would like to have a main repo, with the basic software which I install in the server and only the custom things in another repos, what is the best way to do it?

I tried to use the same repo, changing branches according to the project but sometimes when I want to change something cross projects I mess everything up.

Another thing I tried was delete the .git from my server and start a new repo and add only the files I have changed, the problem is, there are so many files not included in the repo that sometimes is hard to know which files I have changed and which ones are just the main repo's

Is there a best practice to do it?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question, my first reaction is to say: it's not a git problem, it's a project management problem.

What I mean is that every language or framework allows you to create some kind of library you can reuse in various projects.

### First solution

Separate in different folders what is common from what is specific.

Then, create a git repository for the common code and a git repository for each project (with the project/client/server name in it).

If needed, use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to import the commmon code as a sub-folder of your projects.

### Second solution

If, for whatever reason, you can not separate separate the common code from the specific, then you are stuck with branches or fork of an existing project.

My solution in that case is to have a git repository for the common code, and on repository per project.

The projects repositories should be forked from the common code.
In your project repository, you should commit your local modifications.
And when you need to import changes form the common project, do it using rebase instead of merge.
This will apply your local modifications on top of the new version of the common code.

This is a simple way of keeping a set of patches on top of another project.

Of course, to use the rebase solution with only one branch, you will need to use "force push" (because the history changed). To avoid that, you can create a new branch each time you do a rebase; think of it as a new project version.